# How to I parse 1500 mills lines of data efficiently?

Tags: python

I have 1,500,000,000 rows of data saved into multiple txt files. The data formatted as following:

```
key1  key2
```

Where key1 is url, and key2 is mysql record row_id.

I wrote following python code to parse the data, but it is slow. 
e.g.

```
import Queue
import threading

class CheckThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, src_folder, dest_folder='check_result'):
        super(CheckThread, self).__init__()
        self._queue = queue
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            file_name = self._queue.get()
            try:
                self._prepare_check(file_name)
            except:
                self._queue.task_done()
                continue
            self._queue.task_done()


def Check(src_folder, workers=12, dest_folder='check_result'):
    queue = Queue.Queue()

    for (dirpath, dirnames, filelist) in os.walk(src_folder):
        for name in filelist:
            if name[0] == '.':
                continue
            queue.put(os.path.join(dirpath, name))

    for worker in xrange(workers):
        worker = str(worker + 1)
        t = CheckThread(queue, src_folder, dest_folder)
        t.start()

    queue.join()


def main(folder, worker=12, out='check_result'):
    try:
        Check(folder, worker, out)
    except:
        return 1
    return 0
```

Each thread parse a one file from the queue.

How do I improve the parsing speed of each file.

Comment: If your code is working and want to improve it, try: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: codereview would probably not like this question, because it's asking a targeted question about how to improve efficiency.  codereview is more for... well, what code reviews are for.  "How do I take this working code and make it more readable, maintainable and scalable?"  On the other hand, this question is more appropriate for Stack Overflow.  OP has asked a targeted question ("how do I improve the efficiency?", though the "should I use another language"? part of the question could be too broad) and submitted a mostly minimal, complete, verifiable sample of the code in question.

Comment: I edited your question trying to understand what you tried to say but I'm not entirely sure about some parts.

Comment: @thinkerou Ok, I think I was a bit too generous in my previous comment.  From what I understand of your question, this code isn't complete.  (Which means codereview would certainly not want it.)  You mention reading `key1` and `key2` from files, requesting data by http and mysql, and checking the body of the result, but none of that is in the code you submitted.  Realize that if you are really requesting **1.5 billion** websites or SQL queries, this will take forever.  12 threads won't help you; this will still likely take months.

Comment: Despite of poor English, the OP actually can improve the clarify with more details.

Comment: The code you have posted is not the source of the bottleneck, it is just boilerplate scaffolding code that surrounds the actual code that does the work. You need to optimize that part of your application - which you have not shown.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein be careful when using billion like that, as a billion is not the same depending on the region you are at. 1500 millions would be better. I still dont understand what he wants to achieve with the `key1  key2` part.

Comment: @Adirio I request http to get body using `key1`.

Comment: key1 is an URL you are requesting? and key2? what do you do with that body? The part of the code you have passed doesn't seem to be the poor configured one, if you edit your message to include an example of 3 or 4 lines of those .txt files and the rest of the methods you use we may be able to help a bit more

Answer (score 0):

## Some suggestions:

1. Returning 1 on error and 0 on success is not pythonic.
2. Never use `except:`, always specify which exceptions you want to catch.
3. Your first `try: ... except: ...` is not the propper structure to use here, you should use a `try: ... finally: ...` that executes the `finally:` part even if the `try:` part raises an exception.
4. Some of the parameters of `CheckThread.__init__()` are not being used.
5. What does `CheckThread._prepare_check()` do?
6. You are not using `worker`.

The changed code would be:

```
import Queue
import threading

class CheckThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, src_folder, dest_folder='check_result'):
        super(CheckThread, self).__init__()
        self._queue = queue
        self.daemon = True
        # Do something with src_folder and dest_folder or delete them from the parameter list

    def run(self):
        while True:
            file_name = self._queue.get()
            try:
                self._prepare_check(file_name)
            finally:
                self._queue.task_done()


def Check(src_folder, workers=12, dest_folder='check_result'):
    queue = Queue.Queue()

    for (dirpath, dirnames, filelist) in os.walk(src_folder):
        for name in filelist:
            if name[0] == '.':
                continue
            queue.put(os.path.join(dirpath, name))

    for worker in xrange(workers):
        worker = str(worker + 1)  # Do something with worker or delete this line
        t = CheckThread(queue, src_folder, dest_folder)
        t.start()

    queue.join()


def main(folder, worker=12, out='check_result'):
    Check(folder, worker, out)
```

Comment: You can replace the nested `for` loops with a `for file in glob.iglob('/some/path/to/files/*.txt'): queue.put(file)`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid His Python knowledge is quite basic so I just made basic recomendations but you are right.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `CheckThread._prepare_check` request and get body.